# tengo un problema con mi PHP, al parecer cuando ingreso cualquier cosa en usuario y contraseña puede iniciar sesión incluso sin ser usuario

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema con mi php, al parecer cuando ingreso cualquier cosa en usuario y contraseña puede iniciar sesión incluso sin ser usuario

```
<?php
     session_start();
     require 'conexion.php';      

     if($_POST['proceso_ingreso']=="iniciando"){
        if($_POST['nombreUsuario']!="" && $_POST['password']!=""){

           #leyendo los paramentros ingresados
           $nombre =    $_POST["nombreUsuario"];
           $password =  $_POST["password"];         

           $query = "SELECT *FROM registro WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND password = '$password'";

           if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)){
                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
           }else if(!$numrows || mysqli_num_rows($resultado)!= 0){
                header('location: paginaDconsulta.php');    
           }else{
                echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos vuelve a ingresarlos";   

           }
       } else{
           echo "Por favor llenar todos los campos"; 
       }
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

te hice unas modificaciones a tu código, cambie la forma en que lo escribiste  te dejo el aquí los cambios.

```
<?php
     session_start();
     require 'conexion.php';


     if($_POST['proceso_ingreso']=="iniciando"){
        if($_POST['nombreUsuario']!="" && $_POST['password']!=""){
            #leyendo los paramentros ingresados
            $nombre =    $_POST["nombreUsuario"];
            $password =  $_POST["password"];


          $query = "SELECT *FROM registro WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND password = '$password'";
          $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){

                header('location: paginaDconsulta.php');

            }else{

                echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos vuelve a ingresarlos"; 
            }

        }else{

            echo "Por favor llenar todos los campos"; 

        }
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo alternativo, aun así, utilizaría [mysqli_prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php), ya que tu código es vulnerable ante ataques de [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'conexion.php';      

    if($_POST['proceso_ingreso']=="iniciando"){
        //empty — Determina si una variable está vacía.
        if(!empty($_POST['nombreUsuario']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

            //leyendo los paramentros ingresados.            
            //mysqli_real_escape_string — Escapa los caracteres especiales de una cadena para usarla en una sentencia SQL.
            $nombre =    mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST["nombreUsuario"]);
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            //Sentencia.
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM registro WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1");

            //Comprobamos si existe registro.
            if (mysqli_num_rows($query)===1){           
                header('location: paginaDconsulta.php');    
            }else{
                echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos vuelve a ingresarlos."; 
            }

        } else{
           echo "Por favor llenar todos los campos."; 
        }
    }
?>
```